# Laravel query builder not returning the correct sql statement, the strings look like variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have the following Laravel query, it does not appear to be returning the $abort and $pend variables as strings:

```
$abort = "Aborted";
$pend = "Pending";
$transactions = DB::table('callpay_transactions')
->select(DB::raw('SUBSTR(created,1,7) as YrMth') ,DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_sales'  ))
->where('status', '!=', $abort)
->where('status', '!=', $pend)
->groupBy(DB::raw('SUBSTR(created,1,7)'))
    ->toSql();
    
dd($transactions);
```

The return sql query is as follows

```
"select SUBSTR(created,1,7) as YrMth, SUM(amount) as total_sales from `callpay_transactions` where `status` != ? and `status` != ? group by SUBSTR(created,1,7)"
```

Any ideas as to why my $abort and $pend variables show as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i thing that is because of prepared statment and ? also indicate a placeholder while using prepared statment in php.
instead of to sql if you us get you will see the result.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, its exactly that weirdly, I was debugging for other errors on my SQL statement and happened to see that when output to SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the full output with your parameters in place, you can do the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$abort = "Aborted";
$pend = "Pending";

$transactions = DB::table('callpay_transactions')
->select(DB::raw('SUBSTR(created,1,7) as YrMth') ,DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_sales'  ))
->where('status', '!=', $abort)
->where('status', '!=', $pend)
->groupBy(DB::raw('SUBSTR(created,1,7)'));
    
dd(Str::replaceArray('?', $transactions->getBindings(), $transactions->toSql()));
```

That will replace the ? characters with their actual binding values from your query.